# How do I do this in a more idiomatic way with RSpec and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

Doesn't work:

```
feature "home: don't list inactive flash sales" do
  let(:inactive_flash_sale) { create(:inactive_flash_sale, active: false) }

  scenario "does not list inactive flash sales" do
    visit spree.root_path
    expect(page).to_not have_content(inactive_flash_sale.name)
  end
end
```

Works:

```
feature "home: don't list inactive flash sales" do    
  scenario "does not list inactive flash sales" do
    inactive_flash_sale = create(:inactive_flash_sale, active: false)
    visit spree.root_path
    expect(page).to_not have_content(inactive_flash_sale.name)
  end
end
```

The above won't pass in the first form, but it will in the second. It's because the Factorygirl part isn't initialized until after visit in the first version, but it's initialized before on the second. This doesn't let me use let though which is the idiomatic way to use RSpec these days. What am I doing wrong or is this how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply replace `let` by `let!`, this will create the object directly.